# Can’t delete payment method because active subscriptions but no active or hidden subscriptions

Tags: iphone

I keep getting charged every month but there is no active subscriptions or hidden payments showing.
How do I track it down and remove the subscription?

The payment shows it is from Apple Pay.
And why won’t it let me delete the credit card.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to our site. :) Can I ask you to clarify your post by including how you've checked for your subscriptions? Also, you've used the *iCloud* tag, but it's not clear why? Did you mean to use that tag? If so, can you also clarify that. If not, can you please change your tags so that they're relevant for your post. This will help ensure you get the right people looking at your question.

Comment: One would presume that whatever is being charged (credit card, etc.) would have a record of that. Calling the card issuer and asking for details on who is charging what would be a good start. And as it is *possible* the charges are fraudulent you can tell customer service that you want to verify the charges are not fraud.

Comment: Ok I edited the question to give a bit more details